xtensor transpose not working as expected
I've come across this simple tranpose example :
        // Create a 3x2x2 tensor
        xt::xarray<double>::shape_type shape = {3, 2, 2};
        xt::xarray<double> data = xt::arange<double>(12).reshape(shape);

        // Print the original array
        std::cout << "Original data (shape: " << xt::adapt(data.shape()) << "):\n" << data << "\n";

        // Transpose with a specific permutation
        auto transposed = xt::eval(xt::transpose(data, {2, 1, 0}));

        // Print the transposed array
        std::cout << "Transposed data (shape: " << xt::adapt(transposed.shape()) << "):\n"
                  << transposed << "\n";

which prints :

Original data (shape: {3, 2, 2}):
{{{  0.,   1.},
  {  2.,   3.}},
 {{  4.,   5.},
  {  6.,   7.}},
 {{  8.,   9.},
  { 10.,  11.}}}
Transposed data (shape: {2, 2, 3, 0}):
{}


I don't understand what im doing wrong?
I wrote this simple example because the more complex one didn't work.
